# Error - near ":": syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting IDENTIFIER or clock

Tags: macros, system-verilog, uvm

I created my own my_macros file:

```
`ifndef MY_MACROS_SV
`define MY_MACROS_SV

// MACRO: 'my_fatal_err
// calls uvm_fatal in case the assertion is not correct
`define my_fatal(condition, msg )\
   assert (condition) else\
`uvm_fatal("FATAL ERROR", msg)\
\
`define add_rand(mem_type, mem)\
   case (mem_type)\
     "int": add_rand_int(mem);\
     "bit": add_rand_bit(mem);\    
     default: `uvm_fatal("FATAL ERROR", "type is not supported")\ 
     endcase  



`endif  //MY_MACROS_SV
```

`mem_type` expects a string, and `mem` is a member of class.

I got the following compilation error:

> at ..\sv\my_macros.sv(19): near ":": syntax error, unexpected ':',
>   expecting IDENTIFIER or clock.

Line 19 is the `default:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate your 2 macros:

```
`ifndef MY_MACROS_SV
`define MY_MACROS_SV

// MACRO: 'my_fatal_err
// calls uvm_fatal in case the assertion is not correct
`define my_fatal(condition, msg )\
   assert (condition) else\
`uvm_fatal("FATAL ERROR", msg)

`define add_rand(mem_type, mem)\
   case (mem_type)\
     "int": add_rand_int(mem);\
     "bit": add_rand_bit(mem);\    
     default: `uvm_fatal("FATAL ERROR", "type is not supported")\ 
     endcase  



`endif  //MY_MACROS_SV
```